# My selfbot only responded to me and not other users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I run the code and send "xd", selfbot replies "lmao", but if another user writes "xd", selfbot does not reply "lmao", What do I do to make it respond to any user or bot?

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

#TOKEN
TOKEN = "u token"

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = "x")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I ready")

@b.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "xd":
        await message.channel.send("lmao")

b.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```

Comment: Selfbots are no longer supported **and** against the [Discord ToS](https://discord.com/terms). The `on_message` event can't "see" messages of other users anymore. The returned `message.content` will always be `None`/empty.

Answer (score 2):

you cant do on_message for commands anymore so i recomand you do something like this

```
@b.command()
async def xd(ctx):
    await ctx.send("lmao")
```

**self botting is agaist discord TOS**